# Resume two AVAudioPlayer after interruption ends

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I'm using two AVAudioPlayer objects that I play together. When an interruption occurs, I pause both objects and when the interruption ends, I play both AVAudioPlayer objects but the strange thing is, the first one plays but another doesn't play. If I play the second player first then the second player gets played but the first one doesn't. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

```
//This isn't a solution, but should work fine in case you need to want like this !!

//While resuming your first AVAudioPlayer object
NSTimer *timer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self selector:@selector(playSecondObject) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

[AVAudioPlayerObject1 play] //from pause
```

}

```
- (void) playSecondObject
{
[AVAudioPlayerObject2 play]; 
//The timer will fire and call this method and can play second object, 
the time difference can be checked by you to set the exact that what you want?
}

//Hope this helps
```

Comment: Tried but doesn't work. The strange things is I am using mp3 audio format and if I use caf format things are at it's best and both are played even without the timer. But the caf is so much at size that I can not deal with. :(